# When inserting a range with INDIRECT, is it possible to have a "dynamic" sum in the end of it, no matter how many or few rows is injected?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel i have a formula,

```
=INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32")
```

Where F32, actually referes to a counter that counts amount of rows in another sheet, and inserts the number there. That means it can be a variable amount of rows inserted. For example F2:F39, or F2:F45

In the bottom of the rows injected, i want to sum up all the numbers and have a top horizontal line. Is there any way to automatically add this sum? For example it injects into A1:15, then the sum should be in A16, but if its A1:20, then the sum should show in A21

Comment: Wouldn't that formula just return an error?  `INDIRECT` accepts a text string rather than a range reference.... `INDIRECT(A1)` returns a reference error, `INDIRECT("A1")` returns the value that's in A1.  Should it be `=INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32")`?

Comment: Sure, that does not matter for the question though.

Comment: Maybe, if you've got 365, `=VSTACK(INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32"),SUM(INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32")))`?

Comment: A [non-volatile](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) way of writing the INDIRECT could also be `MyOtherSheet!$F$2:INDEX(MyOtherSheet!$F:$F,COUNTA(MyOtherSheet!$F:$F)+1)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook How to put this dynamically "under" the rows injected? Say it inserts in column A1:A15, this automatically is shown in A16?

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F”&A1)` would be a valid way to create a reference that is fixed starting at F2 and continues to a row number that is in cell A1.  I worry about your “injects it into.”  Excel formulas pull data into a range that includes the cell with the formula, not be “sending” it somewhere.  That’s more the role of VBA.  O365’s dynamic arrays create some possibilities but still involve “pulling” the data to the location of the formula.

Comment: Yes the indirect thing is working, i have no problem with the indirect function it self. I am asking how to sum those values together, in the immedeate cell under the inject

Answer (score 0):

To make things a proper answer, you use something like the following:

```
=INDIRECT(  "'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F"  &  'MyOtherSheet'F32  )
```

Notice that the reference to F32 is not typed out IN the string the way you have it but rather the string ends with a row number still needed and you join ("concatenate" if you prefer the word, but connecting two text pieces with `&` is called properly called a "union" or joining of the pieces) the value in F32 to the string's end.

For that to happen, the "F32" must be an actual cell reference so that Excel reads the value in the cell and appends that value. As you have it where the literal "F32" is part of the string given to `INDIRECT` Excel takes the letters and tries to act upon the string so presented. It never realizes you meant it to actually read the cell instead and take the value from there.

I said "like the following" above because there are various ways this arises, and so various ways to work your way through the forest, so to speak. For example, you might have a cell reference, not just a number for the number of rows or how far down. So then it'd read that, and go to that cell looking for the value. In your formula, it's told to go to all the cells from F2 to F32 and act upon what it finds in them... a problem if it would follow orders... but `INDIRECT` will only do so with the first cell in such a string, so it only provides what F2 has.

But, another variation would be that you want one of the above things:  that you want to put an actual cell reference in F32, not a number of rows, or the row to end at. So, instead of putting "43" in F32 to get F44 as the end of the range (F2:F44), you want to put "F44" in F32 so that you are directly telling it what cell to end on. In that case, the formula I gave would be VERY SLIGHTLY different:

```
=INDIRECT(  "'MyOtherSheet'!F2:"  &  'MyOtherSheet'F32  )
```

Do you spot the difference? Yes, VERY slightly different:  instead of the string ending with "!F2:F" and the F32 cell having a number to become the row number, it drops that last "F" to end with "!F:" so that whatever full cell reference (letter and number, not just a number like before) will be joined to the end of the string and the range will be specified correctly.

This is a devil in the details kind of thing and one must be precise after carefully thinking out what needs doing. It's even more... interesting... when you wish to specify a Named Range for `INDIRECT` to read for the value to use OR... when you wish to have it find the name of a Named Range and bring back the actual Named Range itself. `INDIRECT` can be very tricky to use.

Being tricky to use is a big reason for avoiding it, and vastly more important than any concern on Earth about the formula being volatile. Using `INDEX` when possible as `Darren Bartrup-Cook` brings up is both usually possible AND often easier to do when having Excel calculate the value to use. (So not when you want to directly enter "F44" in cell F32, but when cell F32 has a formula to figure out that you want cell F44 to be the end of the range.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i don't see this answering my question though. I have the indirect thing working with getting a range from another sheet. But my question still is, how can i have a SUM injected after the range, which can be of different length.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports VSTACK(), you could do

`=VSTACK(INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32"),SUM(INDIRECT("'MyOtherSheet'!F2:F32")))`

Edit: I see that @Darren Bartrup-Cook provided this answer in the comments already. Apologies